# Верстка в таблицах или в дивах

Tags: html, вёрстка

> Сделан вопросом из ответа в теме: [Разметка таблицы html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/15251/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-html) (@ХэшКод)

Вчера только говорили про верстку в таблицах или в дивах, я так и не понял, почему лучше в дивах. Если не сложно, приведите несколько аргументов в защиту дивов или иной разметки, т.к. я пытаюсь частично перейти на дивы, но так и не понял, почему это лучше. Вот, к примеру, вопрос по диву, как расположить два дива так, чтобы информация была на одной строке, но часть в левой части, а другая в правой. Как это сделать таблицей довольно просто

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align=left>
        </td>
        <td align=right>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @bizovoya Уважаемый участник, мы перенесли Ваш вопрос в новую тему согласно формату форума.

Answer (score 6):

Все это легко гуглится по запросу "*блочная верстка*".

Из **плюсов** блочной верстки можно отметить **меньший размер кода**, **меньшее количество тегов** и **гибкость кода**: зачастую блоки можно менять местами без изменения отображения страницы, что позволяет поместить важную информацию ближе к началу страницы. Также, блочной версткой можно заверстать всевозможные сложные элементы, например, игровые карты ([ссылка](http://urdecker.jet-host.ru/decker.html?lang=en)) или, что встречается чаще, всевозможные иконки в углу нужного элемента. Плюс, преставьте ситуацию, что у вас есть каталог на 100 наименований (картинка + текст + форма) и надо удалить из середины несколько товаров. В таблице вы все это замучаетесь двигать, а при блочной верстке вы просто удалите ненужные блоки, а все остальное рассчитает браузер.

**Минусами** блочной верстки являются **требования к кросбраузерности** css, большой **размер файла css**, **отсутствие** вменяемого **вертикального выравнивания** и **не** самый **очевидный способ растяжения элементов** при переполнении.
Из всего вышесказанного можно сделать вывод, что **верстка должна быть смешанной**. То есть, общую структуру страницы лучше сверстать блоками, а вот ссылки по центру верхнего меню, табличные данные и прочие элементы, где важно выравнивание дочерних элементов относительно друг друга, можно сделать таблицами.

Даю пару ссылок на уже готовую блочную верстку: http://studioad.ru/index/0-10 и http://csstemplater.com/.

И пример верстки сообщений в гостевой книге:

1. Вариант 1:

   ```
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td align="left">title</td>
           <td align="right">date</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td colspan="2" align="left">text</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
   ```
2. Вариант 2:

   ```
   <div class="mess">
       <div class="head">
           <div class="date">date</div>
           title
       </div>
       <div class="text">
           text
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

CSS:

```
.mess{}
.mess .head{}
.mess .head .date{float:right}
.mess .text{}
```

Как видно, вариант 2 длиннее примерно на треть. Однако, когда сообщений становится много, второй вариант выходит вперед за счет меньшего размера разметки. А если надо будет добавить пару дополнительных полей? Если отодвинуть дату от края или вообще, выводить ее слева? Во втором варианте это можно сделать правкой пары строк в CSS файле. А вот в первом придется ковыряться со структурой. Плюс, если дать код стороннему верстальщику, по названиям классов во втором варианте он догадается о значении div'ов. А вот в первом ему придется поломать голову.

И, напоследок: `javascript:alert(document.getElementsByTagName('*').length);void(0);` — проверьте себя).

Answer (score 3):

Вот ваш код:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align=left>
        </td>
        <td align=right>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

А вот мой:

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

B css:

```
.left, .right {
width: 70px;
font-weight: bold;
float: left;
}
.right {
font-weight: normal;
width: 100px;
}
```

Еще вопросы есть?